# .NET Monitoring file operations on a NAS

Tags: .net, windows-services, monitoring, filesystemwatcher, polling

I'm looking for a good and stable way to monitor file changes (created/deleted/renamed etc.) on a NAS (mounted as a share).

I know there's a *FileSystemWatcher*-Object provided by .NET, but also I heard that its not reliable on remote storage devices.

I'm thinking of polling remote devices and check those files wether they've changed (diff with previous collected file-properties) or not.

**Edit: Concrete Requirements:**

- Monitor file / folder changes on directories which are on a NAS (given are the pathes and maybe some kind of filter)
- Log the changes: Best would be on file-level, saying 'file-x renamed/created/deleted', but it's also possible on folder-level, saying 'something changed in folder-x'
- Ability to run external executables
- Run as Windows Service on WinServer (No specific .NET version required)

Are there any common techniques or best-practices to solve this?

**Edit: How to uniquely identify a file?**

A file can't be identified via their name (because it can change).

But is it possible to identify a file uniquely with a last-modified/created timestamp (miliseconds, in a 64bit integer) like Onkelborg suggested? Or do you have any other ideas?

Answer (score 1):

You want to keep the number of directories and files quite small - you need to traverse every directory you are interested in, and get some kind of "tag" of each and every file. You need to keep a list of all files with their "tags" to have something to compare against. The "tag" could be either "last modified date" or file length, or both. (I recommend "last modified date". I don't recommend file length.)

I think you should be more specific, what's your requirements? Anything special? If not, what I wrote is what you need: Build a tree recursively, wait, build again, compare, iterate.

Comment: Hi onkelborg, thanks for your answer, I edited the concrete requirements in my question.